# How to execute code after Quick Look Preview Panel is closed?

Tags: macos, cocoa, quicklook, ikimagebrowserview

I have an `IKImageBrowserView` and i activated the Quick Look Preview Panel for the items in the `IKImageBrowserView` (via `[browser setCanControlQuickLookPanel:true];`).

I want to execute some code after the user closed the Quick View Panel. How can i hook into this?

Comment: Not until now. I finally decided to make my own image preview panel.